# Divs wont stay in line

Tags: html, css

How come my divs stay in line in a row like this: [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k7vcxvhj/)

```
<div class="row solve-item-row">
    <div class="solve-item" style="background:red"> 
        some text
    </div>
    <div class="solve-item" style="background: green">          
    </div>
    <div class="solve-item" style="background: blue">
    </div>
</div>


.solve-item-row {
    width: 100%;
}

.solve-item {
    display: inline-table;
    height: 100px;
    width: 30%;
}
```

But as soon as I add text or image or anything they get all thrown off like this: [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x3c1qjjk/) ?

Comment: Add `vertical-align: top;` to the inner divs

Comment: `vertical-align: middle;` would work as well.